# How do I Run Jasmine Unit Tests Synchronously?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I am currently using chutzpah to run Jasmine JavaScript unit tests in Visual Studio. I have a globally scoped DOM element that i need to reset each time a couple of my tests run.  I am currently using `beforeEach()` to clear out the DOM element so the next test can use and populate accordingly.  However, it looks like i am running into async problems where the element is being cleared in one test while executing in a different test.  Bottom line: Is there any way to run each test synchronously in Jasmine? Current structure looks something like this:

```
describe('baseView', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
        $('#elementToClear').html('');
    });

    it('run 2.', function () {
        var baseView = new BaseView();
        baseView.populateElement();
        expect($('#elementToClear').html()).toBe('populated')
    });

    it('run 1.', function () {
        var baseView = new BaseView();
        baseView.populateElement();
        expect($('#elementToClear').html()).toBe('populated')
    });
});
```

Comment: create a new element for each test.

Comment: I guess my example is too contrived.  Really there is a plugin doing the work behind the scenes that creates the element. On that note i may have answered my own question.  This has some pretty nasty stink to it. If i would stop being lazy the real answer should be to abstract the plugin.

Comment: However, that does not really answer my question.  Can you run Jasmine unit tests synchronously?

Comment: Hmm.  interesting.  I'll do some more playing around.

Comment: what does `.popuplateElement` do? is that async?

Comment: Jasmine cli has a flag "random" that defaults to true, it could be the case...